# Why children for a selector not works in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change `background color` of `li` having a class with `jquery children`, but it is not working.
Following is the url where I test it : http://jsfiddle.net/kFUqK/1/

I changed the code

```
$('ul.level-2').children().css('background-color', 'red');
$('ul.level-2').children('.level-33').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

to

```
//$('ul.level-2').children().css('background-color', 'red');
$('ul.level-2').children('.level-33').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Then I found `li.level-33` has not changed with its background.

Any reason for this?

Comment: you can use `$('ul.level-2 li.level-33')` selector

Comment: @Rohan Kumar Check the updated fiddle, you can use `find()` to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the jQuery docs:

> The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only
>   travels a **single level** down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

So you want `find`.